# Use of the phrase 'fetal position'

Tags: word-usage

[image]

Is this called fetal position? If yes, can we say:

---

She is sitting in fetal position.

---

Or: She is sitting with her head bowed closed to abdomen.

Answer (score 3):

I just googled **fetal position**, and this is what appeared on the top of my display...

[image]

...so I think that's sufficient evidence that OP's picture does indeed depict the "fetal position".

---

EDIT: In case @JasonBassford's comment below gets deleted...

> *The actual syntax of the sentence asked about is wrong—it needs an article.
>
>   People don't sit in fetal position.
>
>   They sit in **a / the** fetal position.*

Comment: Except,  that aside, the actual syntax of  the sentence asked about is wrong—it needs an article. People don't *sit in fetal position*, they *sit in **a / the** fetal position.*

Comment: @JasonBassford: Good point. But is it significant that I didn't even *notice* the error?